# How to login into Instagram using Python Requests?

Tags: python, ajax, cookies, python-requests, instagram

I am using the following code to make a Python Request to login into my Instagram account. I am running this on local.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import re
from pprint import pprint
import json


time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = f"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/"

payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'enc_password': 'PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:password',
    'queryParams': "{}",
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false',
    'stopDeletionNonce': "", 
    'trustedDeviceRecords': "{}"
}


response = requests.get(link)
csrf = response.cookies['csrftoken']
print(csrf)

response = requests.post(login_url, data=payload, headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Xequested-Xith": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/",
    "X-CSRFtoken": csrf,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "www.instagram.com",
    "Origin": "https://www.instagram.com"
})

response_json = json.loads(response.text)
pprint(response_json)
```

The response I receive after running the above code shows that I request is not authenticated:

`{'authenticated': False, 'status': 'ok', 'user': True}`

How can I login to Instagram using requests? Is there an updated method?

Answer (score 1):

In general, these use cases lend themselves perfectly for selenium, scrapy, playwright or puppeteer. I do not have an instagram account, so I don't know if this works, but in theory it might return a valid response:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'csrftoken': '9e7U8qRNqAbazRC0kwrRgyN2okh1kihx',
    'mid': 'YsM1_AALAAEG2fGCvkPXE5DVlJD0',
    'ig_did': '494394E2-A583-4F01-BC32-5E4344FE2C4D',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'X-CSRFToken': '9e7U8qRNqAbazRC0kwrRgyN2okh1kihx',
    'X-Instagram-AJAX': 'c6412f1b1b7b',
    'X-IG-App-ID': '936619743392459',
    'X-ASBD-ID': '198387',
    'X-IG-WWW-Claim': '0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'csrftoken=9e7U8qRNqAbazRC0kwrRgyN2okh1kihx; mid=YsM1_AALAAEG2fGCvkPXE5DVlJD0; ig_did=494394E2-A583-4F01-BC32-5E4344FE2C4D',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}

data = {
    'enc_password': '#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:10:1656960533:ARxQAMMwb3Yd6w3UdaFGt0Q3mTZ7lMDJHHmZFLaGEfQahXJOTxqb35Q/ZGC3B70DxZRhKcnaf3xImXyL7EFseRF/yZG4dvauui/LzLU7oAHK3rYHSYsjPjQTham/5DFXq6m4foqB5fIiJoChT+ng58EDUkFA1A==',
    'username': 'somerandomemail@hotmail.com',
    'queryParams': '{}',
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false',
    'stopDeletionNonce': '',
    'trustedDeviceRecords': '{}',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
```

If you run into security issues, try the same but with cloudscraper instead of requests library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access Instagram with only `requests` as far as I know.
Last time I tried, I'd to create an app within the facebook developer account and make an accesstoken from the Facebook / Instagram Graph API to access Instagram and make login stuffs. With that, you can not only login to your account but also you can post contents from that.

Long story short, refer [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) and this should get your job done!

**Edit:**

```
# Sharing on Instagram...
insta = facebook.GraphAPI(facebookUserAccessToken)
InstaSend = insta.put_photo(open(IMAGEPATH, 'rb'), message=TEXT)
if InstaSend:
    print('\nInstagram Share Successful!')

# Sharing on Facebook...
face = facebook.GraphAPI(facebookPageAccessToken)
face.put_object(
    parent_object=facebookPageID,
    connection_name="feed",
    message=TEXT,
    )
faceSend = face.put_photo(open(IMAGEPATH, 'rb'), message=TEXT)
if faceSend:
    print('\nFacebook Share Successful!')
```

This above part of code dates back to 2019 that I'd written to automatically share the content on different social media platforms once the video was published on my YouTube channel. I haven't used this since then and I doubt this would work for you as is. Some code **might** needs to be changed in order for it to work as the Graph API is actively being updated by Meta. However what I believe is the process has gotten easier.

Additionally, you can checkout "Justin Stolpe" on YouTube for more insights on this topic.

Comment: Co-incidentally, I already have a Facebook Developer account with everything set-up. Could you elaborate what requests do I send for login? I just need some relevant and specific documentation.